# unable to load CSS style images when deploy angular coreui in off root Nginx

Tags: css

I deployed my coreui angular app in ngnix as off root deployment. When i launch the  App URL, I see few images ( rendered from CSS classes as shown below) not rendering in the UI.

CSS Class to render image:

```
 .icon-speech {
    content: "\e02c" !important;
}

enter code here
```

Ngnix config file:

```
server {
 #-------

location /rig-activity {

            set $url http://edge_rig-activity-service;
                        rewrite ^/rig-activity(.*) $1 break;
                        proxy_pass $url;
                }

                location /rig-activity-ui/ {
                    #enable for debug mode
                    #proxy_pass http://localhost:4200;


                    #root /www/html;
                    alias /www/rig-activity-ui/;

                    #index  index.html index.htm;

                    try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri/ /rig-activity-ui/index.html;
                }
}
```

Here is screenshot where my images not rendering: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK4lY.png)